# What the difference between vagrant-hostsupdater and vagrant-hostmanager?

Tags: vagrant, hosts

What the difference between this 2 vagrant plugins? I'm using vagrant-hostmanager which can update /etc/hosts file on host machine, as well as on guest machine, supports multi-machine vagrant setup. But when I tried to use this tool https://github.com/roots/trellis I noticed that it uses vagrant-hostsupdater. Are there any benefits of this plugin compared to vagrant-hostmanager?

Comment: There's also https://github.com/oscar-stack/vagrant-hosts which looks like it does the same or a similar thing.
Seems like there's quite a bit of "not invented here" happening, this could all be one plug-in with arguments for the various divergent behaviors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**Hostsupdater**](https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater) updates the `/etc/hosts` only of the host machine.

[**Hostsmanager**](https://github.com/devopsgroup-io/vagrant-hostmanager) updates the `/etc/hosts` of both the vm and the host machine.